# Uncaught ReferenceError: calcMod is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm creating this D&D Character Generator app and I have two buttons: Roll The Dice and Keep the Dice. This is a way to either randomly generate a character or to input stats of your own. I have refactored my code so that these functions write to the HTML at the end of the script. Now however, I have certain prerequisites for the information being laid out. For instance the ket variables (Dexterity, Constitution, etc.) are dependent on whether you roll the dice or keep the dice. I have put in an if/else statement that I think is throwing things off.  Here is the code.

```
//Variables
var dex;
var con;
var str;
var intel;
var wis;
var cha;
var hitPoints;

if($("#RollTheDice").click()) {
    dex = statRoll();
    con = statRoll();
    str = statRoll();
    intel = statRoll();
    wis = statRoll();
    cha = statRoll();
}else if ($("KeepTheDice").click()) {
    dex = +document.getElementById("Dex").value;
    con = +document.getElementById("Con").value
    str = +document.getElementById("Strength").value;
    intel = +document.getElementById("Intel").value;
    wis = +document.getElementById("Wis").value;
    cha = +document.getElementById("Cha").value;
    hitPoints = +document.getElementById("HP").value;
}

//Modifiers
var dexmod = calcMod(dex);
var conmod = calcMod(con);
var strmod = calcMod(str);
var intelmod = calcMod(intel);
var wismod = calcMod(wis);
var chamod = calcMod(cha);
```

Now I know something I'm doing isn't quite right but I don't know what. I imagine it is the if/else statement.

The error I get is

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: calcMod is not defined
Anonymous Function
```

I'm a little stuck here if anybody would oblige.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me. You never defined `calcMod` anywhere, or at least not where you are trying to call it. Please search for [Uncaught ReferenceError](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+Uncaught+ReferenceError).

Comment: So...  did you define calcMod()?  If so, what's the code?

Comment: Where did you define calcMod function?

Comment: As a note: I don't think that `if ( $("#RollTheDice").click() )`  does what you think it does. ([jQuery.click](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click): If it is called with no parameter then `[...]This method is a shortcut for[...].trigger( "click" )` and the result of that call will be always a truthy value)

Comment: Additionally, just as a friendly note, try to keep things... the same.  For instance, if you are using the three-letter abbreviations for your stats, do so always, don't mostly use them, then use 'intel' instead of 'int' and 'strength' instead of 'Str'.  In fact, maybe shorten hitpoints to 'hit'?  It's just good form to keep variables in the same format.

Comment: Like an idiot, I forgot to include the calcMod function in the code. Now I'm getting an error where it won't put anything above level 1 in the results.

Comment: I have a function

`//XP and Level
function XPlevel(XP, level) {
 if((XP >= 0 && XP < 300) && level === 1) {
  level = 1;
 } else if ((XP >= 300 && XP <900) || level === 2) {
  level = 2;
 } else if ((XP >= 900 && XP <2700) || level ===3) {
  level = 3;
 } else if ((XP >= 2700 && XP < 6500) || level === 4){
  level = 4;
 } else if ((XP >= 6500 & XP < 14000) || level === 5){
  level = 5;
 }...level=20
 return level;
}

XPlevel(XP, level);`

Comment: Is it somehow out of scope?

Comment: Out of scope? I'm not sure. It should be for both Keep the Dice and Roll the Dice so I left it as a function on its own.

Comment: It doesn't come up with an error

Comment: Please give your question a useful title, not "Oh let me explain"

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `if` to react to clicks in Javascript/jQuery. You pass a function to `.click()`, and that function gets called when someone clicks on the element.

```
$("#RollTheDice").click(function() {
    dex = statRoll();
    con = statRoll();
    str = statRoll();
    intel = statRoll();
    wis = statRoll();
    cha = statRoll();
});
$("KeepTheDice").click(function() {
    dex = +document.getElementById("Dex").value;
    con = +document.getElementById("Con").value
    str = +document.getElementById("Strength").value;
    intel = +document.getElementById("Intel").value;
    wis = +document.getElementById("Wis").value;
    cha = +document.getElementById("Cha").value;
    hitPoints = +document.getElementById("HP").value;
});
```

Comment: Ack!  While not incorrect, putting the function inline with the click() call is...  just not a good idea.  Create a function and call that in click() if you must.

Comment: @JesseWilliams This is extremely idiomatic use of jQuery. Named functions are generally only used if you need to bind the same method to different events, or need to be able to call the function independently of an event.

Comment: This gave me an issue with hitPoints and left all my stats with NaNs.

Comment: There's almost certainly other things wrong with your application, since you don't seem to understand the basic principles of how to write JS applications or how to use jQuery. But since you only showed this little snippet of code, that's all I could correct.

Comment: Well, if you want the whole code I'm happy to give it to you for a look over, but yeah, I'm a n00b and I'm trying to teach myself javascript the best I can. No need for the comment.

Comment: @user3605374 Try to simplify your problem down to a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then we can try to help you with it.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that the simple answer is that `calcMod()` isn't defined in your code (at least not in context of where it's called).  Also `*.click()` isn't going to check for that element to be clicked.  You want an OnClick() event called by your button that will call a function, something like:

```
 <button onclick="someFunction()">Click Here!</button>
```

You can keep the `if-statement` and evaluate for the name of the calling button (I believe).

Lastly, just to consolidate my note above, try to keep your variables named the same.  Stick with three-letter abbreviations everywhere if that's what you want to use.  It's just better form.

Comment: I discourage from using inline event handler, on the one hand it forces you to pollute the global namespace with the callback methods and on the other hand it makes the code difficult to maintain.

Comment: It's actually fairly easy to maintain.  But regardless, the .click() call the OP is making currently isn't going to do what he thinks it's going to do anyhow.  I was simply offering an alternative that would actually function.

Comment: I tried the button onclick function and it gives me NaN for all of the stats